# Loopback datasource discoverAndBuildModels equivalent for noSQL tables?

Tags: loopbackjs

I'm trying to find something like datasource.discoverAndBuildModels() for my MongoDB tables.

I know this is probably kind of weird, but what I'm trying to do is create a datasource dynamically, point it at existing tables (that don't have premade model configurations), have it pick up these tables and allow me to query them. It looks like discoverAndBuildModels() would have been perfect for my needs, but that this only works for relational databases? Is this true?

If so, would it be worth using a relational database for my needs, or is there a way to get this to work using MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

`discovery` is not supported for NoSQL databases. However, you can use `instance introspection`. See http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Creating+models+from+unstructured+data